# Salesforce sfdx:data:tree:export for objects with lookups

Tags: salesforcedx

We have a list of MyCustomObject__c which have a Master/Detail relationship with Account and we set on the Account a reference to the last of MyCustomObject__c, which we call Last_MyCustomObject__c.

When we try to export the data using `sfdx force:data:tree:export -p -q myquery.txt" the export fails saying reference MyCustomObject__c not found for Last_MyCustomObject__c. What is the right way get this data so it can be imported into a scratch org?

Ideally if we would write a query that would be like

```
Select ID, Name, Last_MyCustomObject__c from Account
```

or

```
Select ID, Name, Last_MyCustomObject__c, (Select Id, Name from MyCustomObject__c where Id = Last_MyCustomObject__c ) from Account.
```

Additionally, if we want to import other objects related to the same Account, how can we do that, if it will not be possible to express the export in a single query?

Comment: Here we are trying to export the data from production, is my scratch org configuration potentially impacting the result?

Comment: oops - thoguht you were trying to import to somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You have to start at the top of the tree to get the whole record. So if you only want the one `MyCustomObject__c` record that is represented by the `Last_MyCustomObject__c` lookup, you have to sort of recreate the behavior in your query:

```
Select ID, Name, Last_MyCustomObject__c, 
      (Select Id, Name from MyCustomObjects__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) 
  From Account
```

Comment: We did that. What about now selecting objects that relate to that account? (Some Contacts?)